# Norway Merkur market from Australia?

Tags: shares, australia

I'm having troubles trying to find a way to buy shares from the Norway Merkur market as an Australian. The Australian banks I contacted are not offering Norway shares.

I'm struggling, and failed to find a way to buy Norway shares.
What would be a good way to do the investment from Australia? I don't have a Norway passport so I can't have a local bank account there.

Comment: Have you tried Interactive Brokers?

Comment: No what’s that? How does it help?

Comment: They're a worldwide brokerage: offices in lots of countries, with access to lots of exchanges.